# Why does Debug Utils Extension requires swap chain device extension?

Tags: vulkan

I want to use a new `VK_EXT_debug_utils`. I did it in a couple of projects already and it worked fine, but today I found that `vkSetDebugUtilsObjectNameEXT` throws a `SIGSEGV`. I spent a good amount of time trying to figure out what were differences between a new project and the old ones. With blind attempts, I figured out that in the new project I didn't specify `VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME` when created a device (because I don't need it) and that caused a crash somehow. I searched in a documentation but could not find any mention of this behavior. Did I miss something important?

Upd.: on Windows, the problem exists as well.

Comment: Indeed, documentation for this extension doesn't mention swapchain to be required. Nor the LunarG's [tutorial](https://www.lunarg.com/new-tutorial-for-vulkan-debug-utilities-extension/). Maybe it's a bug in Your graphics driver? Swapchain extension shouldn't be required.

Comment: @Ekzuzy Yes, I followed this tutorial and, as I told, everything was straightforward until I omitted the swapchain extension. I'm on linux and it's quite painful to update drivers there, I'll try on windows machine later and update the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited: Now fixed) I just saw this issue.  I looked into it quickly by modifying one of Sascha Willems examples and I was able to reproduce this.  It is a Vulkan loader bug, not a driver bug.  I created a Vulkan loader bug [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/issues/54) and resolved the issue.

If you build your own Vulkan loader, you can get a fix now.  Otherwise, you'll have to wait for our next SDK release.

Sorry, but a huge thanks for catching this.

Comment: That sounds cool, thank you for the update! Just curious - can this type of errors be caught by layers?

Comment: Not in this case. The bug caused the layer code not to get loaded when it should have.  In fact, it was initializing the function pointer for the call from the loader to the next layer or ICD to NULL and never setting it to a valid value because it thought the extension wasn't properly enabled, even thought it had been.